# How to share object's methods across components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, spotify, redux-toolkit, react-context

I'm creating a React (functional components) app which is based on Spotify Web API. I have no problems with this API but i have problems with Spotify Web Playback SDK. It's a library which allows browser to control music player. As far as i know it's the only way I can play Spotify music in my app. So i tried to implement it with their official tutorial. But it's based on the singular object **Player** and it has methods such as **setVolume**, **togglePlay** or **nextTrack**. I want to be able to access this methods in different components. And my question is how to share this one object with it's methods? I use redux toolkit for sharing data but i suppose I can't share complex objects like this with it or can I?
I thought about creating **Player** object in a root and pass it with props but then I would have to useState for it in every component to show data from it and the object wouldn't be in sync. Am I misunderstanding something or it's a wrong way of doing it?
I don't need this object overall. What I need is data from it and to be able to call it's methods in components.

[Here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/howtos/web-app-player) is a tutorial that I was following but it has no nested components.
[Here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference#spotifyplayer) is a reference to the Player object that I want to use.

**UPDATE**

I tried to solve it using Context API.

**SpotifyPlayerContext.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const SpotifyPlayerContext = createContext()

export const SpotifyPlayerProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user.value)
    const [spotifyPlayer, setSpotifyPlayer] = useState()

    const initSpotifyPlayer = () => {
        const script = document.createElement("script")
        script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"
        script.async = true
        document.body.appendChild(script)

        window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
            const playerInstance = new window.Spotify.Player({
                name: "Figure Out The Lyrics",
                getOAuthToken: (cb) => { cb(user.token) }
            })

            playerInstance.connect()
            
            playerInstance.addListener("ready", ({ device_id }) => {
                console.log("Device ID", device_id)
                playerInstance.device_id = device_id
                setSpotifyPlayer({...playerInstance})
            })
            playerInstance.addListener("player_state_changed", state => {
                console.log('player state changed', state);
                playerInstance.playback = state;
                setSpotifyPlayer({...playerInstance})
            })
        }
    }

    const value = { spotifyPlayer, setSpotifyPlayer, initSpotifyPlayer }

    return <SpotifyPlayerContext.Provider value={value}> {children} </SpotifyPlayerContext.Provider>
}

export default SpotifyPlayerContext
```

**Player.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { Tooltip } from "react-tooltip"
import SpotifyPlayerContext from "../SpotifyPlayerContext"

const Player = ({ spotifyAPI }) => {
    const { spotifyPlayer, setSpotifyPlayer } = useContext(SpotifyPlayerContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!spotifyPlayer) return
        if (!spotifyPlayer.playback) spotifyAPI.transferMyPlayback([spotifyPlayer.device_id])
        console.log("useEffect in Player", spotifyPlayer)
    }, [spotifyPlayer])

    return spotifyPlayer?.playback ? (
        <button onClick={() => spotifyPlayer.togglePlay()}>toggle</button>
    ) : (
        <div>loading</div>
    )
}

export default Player
```

I'm able to get data from it and when the spotifyPlayer changes the component is re-rendered but when i click the button I get error which says that spotifyPlayer.togglePlay is not a function
So, how am I supposed to access it's methods? I guess that when I assign playerInstance to spotifyPlayer state it looses it's methods but how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think every time `usePlayer` is used, you create another player instance, which probably isn't what you want. Custom hooks don't have this centralized singleton behavior you need out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

There is this line in the tutorial:

```
const player = new window.Spotify.Player(...)
```

Instead of keeping this player instance in just one component, save it in a module that your other components can import:

```
// player.js

let player;

export const savePlayerInstance = (playerInstance) => {
    player = playerInstance;
};

export const getPlayer = () => player;
```

So you would `import { savePlayerInstance } from 'some/path/player'` and call `setPlayer(player)` after the instance is created (the line from your tutorial). Other modules can `import { getPlayer } from 'some/path/player'`, call `getPlayer()` and invoke its methods.

Comment: How to make some component getPlayer() only when the value of object has changed? When I getPlayer() it always returns undefined because it gets it before the parent initializes the player. Also later, when the property of the player would change how the other components should know to getPlayer() again?

Comment: This depends on how you architect your app. The components that rely on an initialized player could for example not be rendered until it exists. If you want true "reactiveness" you could put the player instance in a custom hook or use a context provider. The easiest solution is to set up the player somewhere near the entry point of your app and wait until that is done before rendering more playback-related components.